# Mongoose boolean query within array returns all records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to select certain objects within an array that meet a criteria with Mongoose.

Assume the following records:

```
var Record = {
   records : [{name : "you can't look', isPublic : false},
              {name : "ok you can look', isPublic : true},
              {name : "you can look here too', isPublic : true}]
}
```

And the following query :

```
Record.find({'records.isPublic' : true}, function (error, response) {
  //This returns all the records, rather than just 0 and 2. 
});
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `db.collection.aggregate`, `$unwind` and `$match`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
Record.find({}, {'records': {$elemMatch: {'isPublic': 'true'}}}), function (error, response) {
   // finds everything, but projects only those which 'isPublic': 'true'
});
```